# How do I print the return value on the console?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement, return

I've got a course task to make a calculator in Javascript. I've got the functions for the different operators and the case-switch but I'm struggling with how to print the return values of the functions. Here's the code I've got so far:

```js
let firstValue = prompt("Enter a number");

let secondValue = prompt("Enter a second number");

let operation = prompt("How should these numbers interact");

function addition(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue + secondValue;
}

function subtraction(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue - secondValue;
}

function division(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue / secondValue;
}

function multiplication(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue * secondValue;
}

function powerTo(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue ^ secondValue;
}

switch (operation) {
  case "+":
    addition();
    break;
  case "-":
    subtraction();
    break;
  case "/":
    division();
    break;
  case "*":
    multiplication();
    break;
  case "^":
    powerTo();
    break;
  default:
    console.log("No operation inputted");
    break;
}

console.log(`${firstValue} ${operation} ${secondValue} =`)
```

Comment: Are you [in the same class as this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71847526/102937)?

Comment: switch statements must operate WITHIN a function - consider creating a Calculate() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the result of calling the operation function to a variable, then display that in the console.

You also need to pass arguments to all the functions.

And you should convert the input to a number before using it in calculations. Most of the arithmetic operators will convert it automatically, but `+` will do string concatenation.

```js
let firstValue = Number(prompt("Enter a number"));

let secondValue = Number(prompt("Enter a second number"));

let operation = prompt("How should these numbers interact");

function addition(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue + secondValue;
}

function subtraction(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue - secondValue;
}

function division(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue / secondValue;
}

function multiplication(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue * secondValue;
}

function powerTo(firstValue, secondValue) {
  return firstValue ^ secondValue;
}

let result;

switch (operation) {
  case "+":
    result = addition(firstValue, secondValue);
    break;
  case "-":
    result = subtraction(firstValue, secondValue);
    break;
  case "/":
    result = division();
    break;
  case "*":
    result = multiplication(firstValue, secondValue);
    break;
  case "^":
    result = powerTo(firstValue, secondValue);
    break;
  default:
    console.log("No operation inputted");
    break;
}

console.log(`${firstValue} ${operation} ${secondValue} = ${result}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.
First you need to save the result of the function call to a variable, second you need to pass the arguments to the function and finally in javascript exponents are done using the `**` operator not the `^` operator, `^` is used for a bitwise xor.

Here is your code when it is fixed:

```js
let firstValue = prompt("Enter a number");

let secondValue = prompt("Enter a second number");

let operation = prompt("How should these numbers interact");


function addition(firstValue, secondValue) {
    return firstValue + secondValue;
}

function subtraction(firstValue, secondValue) {
    return firstValue - secondValue;
}

function division(firstValue, secondValue) {
   return firstValue / secondValue;
}

function multiplication(firstValue, secondValue) {
    return firstValue * secondValue;
}

function powerTo(firstValue, secondValue) {
    return firstValue ** secondValue;
}

let result;
switch(operation) {
    case "+" :
        result = addition(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
    case "-":
        result = subtraction(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
    case "/":
        result = division(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
    case "*":
        result = multiplication(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
    case "^":
        result = powerTo(firstValue, secondValue);
        break;
    default:
        console.log("No operation inputted");
        break;
}

console.log(`${firstValue} ${operation} ${secondValue} = ${result}`);
```

However in this case I feel that separating the operations into functions is unnecessary. Here is a cleaned up version:

```js
let firstValue = prompt("Enter a number");

let secondValue = prompt("Enter a second number");

let operation = prompt("How should these numbers interact");

let result;
switch(operation) {
    case "+" :
        result = firstValue + secondValue;
        break;
    case "-":
        result = firstValue - secondValue;
        break;
    case "/":
        result = firstValue / secondValue;
        break;
    case "*":
        result = firstValue * secondValue;
        break;
    case "^":
        result = firstValue ** secondValue;
        break;
    default:
        console.log("No operation inputted");
        break;
}

console.log(`${firstValue} ${operation} ${secondValue} = ${result}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: everyone answered at the same time with the same thing so I thought I would spice my answer up with some unsafe code

```js
const firstValue = prompt("Enter a number");

const secondValue = prompt("Enter a second number");

const operation = prompt("How should these numbers interact");

const expression = `${firstValue} ${operation} ${secondValue}`;

const result = eval(expression);

console.log(`${expression} = ${result}`);
```

Comment: How about that. It's amazing to me how seeing a switch statement operating outside a function seems....wrong...and yet, nope. Never too old to learn something new, though for the life of me I don't know why one would do this :)

Comment: @fnostro I thought I had changed my answer quickly enough that the first wouldn't have disrupted anything lol sorry for you comment looking out of place. There are many better ways to accomplish the task, but I leave best practice for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's a good day when you learn something new. Mind I still think it's "wrong" :) but it works, so yeah...code review :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving the problem. More complicated, but safe and clean.

```
function getNumber(message) {
    let number;
    do {
        number = prompt(message);
        if (isNaN(number)) {
            alert(`${number} is not a number, try again.`);
        } else break;
    } while (true);
    return parseInt(number);
}

function add(offset, x) {
    return offset + x;
}

const operations = {
    "+": add,
};

const firstNumber = getNumber("Enter the first number");
const secondNumber = getNumber("Enter the second number");

let operation;
do {
    operation = prompt("How should these numbers interact");
    if (!operations[operation]) {
        alert(operation + " is not supported");
    } else break;
} while (true);

const calculate = operations[operation];

const result = calculate(firstNumber, secondNumber);
alert("Answer is " + result);
```